# Sharing behaviour between components in Angular 2 with Typescript

Tags: inheritance, angular, typescript, components, composition

I am currently working on an Angular 2 project with Typescript.

I have several components which share the same behaviour : they are all able to show a loader (depending on if they are fetching some data), an error screen (if the fetch failed), and they are all subscribing to the same service (the one that fetch the data). This service is refreshing the data every 30 seconds, and components subscribers are doing **almost** the same thing with the new data.

I could not find a good way to share this behaviour.

I tried to use mixins from typescript, but first, I can not override method I declared in mixin in my component, and second, I still have to declare methods in my components with nothing inside, so my compiler does not complain.

I also tried to use decorator, but my compiler complains because it does not find the method declared in the decorator.

I finally try to use typescript inheritance with a parent component, that do not have any template, it is just a parent class, I use it with "extends ParentComponent", and put all my logic in the ParentComponent. This last method was the easiest one, but I have the strong feeling that this is definitively not the good way (composition over inheritance, etc.)

Is there a way to do it properly ? I come from ruby on rails, something like the "concerns" in ruby would be great.

Comment: so what exactly do you want to share? template? component class?

Answer (score 0):

Create a ParentComponent which holds a router-outlet to hold the unique behaviour as (ChildComponents) and share the data model via a shared service.

Also incorporate lazyloading(route using loadchildren) to get module specific sharedservice.